# Error Compiling C++/CLI Delegate call using Predicate with Array::FindAll()

Tags: c++-cli, compiler-errors, delegates

The following code results in C3867 (...function call missing argument list...) and C3350 (...a delegate constructor expects 2 argument(s)...). What am I doing wrong?

```
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        bool IsEven(int i){
            return (i % 2) == 0;
        }

        Form1(void)
        {
            numbers = gcnew array<int>{
                1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
            };

            array<int> ^even = Array::FindAll(
                numbers, gcnew Predicate<int>(IsEven));
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In C++/CLI you have to pass the actual instance of the type containing the function:

```
 array<int> ^even = Array::FindAll(
    numbers, gcnew Predicate<int>(this, &Test::IsEven));
```

(or make your `IsEven` method `static`)

Comment: And I also forgot the ampersand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following simple console application provides examples of the `FindAll()` method with an `array` in .NET C++/CLI.

This works with Visual Studio 2005 which does not provide support for lambdas. Since your example is using Windows Forms, I provide an extra class  in this Windows console application to show the `Predicate` function from a class when used in the `FindAll()`.

This example shows three different mechanisms for providing a predicate:

- using a class static function available without an object
- using a class method which requires an object be created before using
- a simple C style function which is not a method in a class

This is a very basic sample using `int` however it does also work with more complex data structures as well.

```
// _scrap_net.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

    public ref class Thing1
    {
    private:
        int     iDiv;                  // divisor if specified
    public:
        static bool IsEven(int i){      // static usable without creating an object
            return (i % 2) == 0;        // even number if division has no remainder
        }
        static bool IsOdd(int i){       // static usable without creating an object
            return (i % 2) != 0;        // odd numbered if division has remainder
        }
        bool IsDivisibleBy (int i) {    // non-static must create object before using
            return (i % iDiv) == 0;     // check if division has remainder
        }
        bool IsNotDivisibleBy (int i) { // non-static must create object before using
            return (i % iDiv) != 0;     // check if division has remainder
        }

        Thing1(void) { iDiv = 2; }      // standard constructor
        Thing1(int i) { iDiv = i; }     // constructor with argument to use IsDivisibleBy()
    };

    // standalone function used rather than a class function
    bool IsLessThan10 (int i) {
        return i < 10;
    }

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // sample array of some integers for our example
    array<int> ^numbers = gcnew array<int>{
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
    };

    // our format string to use when printing the array values
    String ^ fmt = gcnew String(L" {0,6}");

    // use a static function in a class as the predicate so object not needed
    array<int> ^even = Array::FindAll(numbers, gcnew Predicate<int>(&Thing1::IsEven));

    Console::WriteLine (L"\n even ");
    for each (int jj in even) {
        Console::Write(fmt, jj);
    }

    // use a standard function as the predicate so class not needed
    array<int> ^lessThan10 = Array::FindAll(numbers, gcnew Predicate<int>(&IsLessThan10));

    Console::WriteLine (L"\n lessThan10 ");
    for each (int jj in lessThan10) {
        Console::Write(fmt, jj);
    }


    // use a special divisor so create an object with that value and use it.
    Thing1 ^ myDiv = gcnew Thing1(3);

    // need to specify the object for the object method in the predicate
    array<int> ^divBy3 = Array::FindAll(numbers, gcnew Predicate<int>(myDiv, &Thing1::IsDivisibleBy));

    Console::WriteLine (L"\n divBy3 ");
    for each (int jj in divBy3) {
        Console::Write(fmt, jj);
    }


    // need to specify the object for the object method in the predicate
    array<int> ^notDivBy3 = Array::FindAll(numbers, gcnew Predicate<int>(myDiv, &Thing1::IsNotDivisibleBy));

    Console::WriteLine (L"\n notDivBy3 ");
    for each (int jj in notDivBy3) {
        Console::Write(fmt, jj);
    }

    Console::WriteLine (L"\nEnd");
    return 0;
}
```

The output from this program looks like the following:

```
 even
      2      4      6      8     10     12     14
 lessThan10
      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9
 divBy3
      3      6      9     12
 notDivBy3
      1      2      4      5      7      8     10     11     13     14
End
```