# How do I forward declare a delegate in C++/CLI?

Tags: .net, syntax, c++-cli, delegates, forward-declaration

How?

The following did not work:

```
delegate MyDelegate;
ref class MyDelegate;
delegate void MyDelegate;
```

The following works for declaration:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(Object ^sender, MyArgs ^args);
```

But using it as a forward declaration gives me

```
error C3756: 'MyNameSpace::MyDelegate': delegate definition conflicts with an existing symbol
```

Comment: One suggestion was to forward declare MyArgs but even that did not help. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

This work's for me;

stdafx.h:

```
public delegate void Handler(bool isit);
```

cli1.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace System;

namespace MY {
   namespace Namespace
   {
       public ref class Objeks
       {
           public: Objeks() {}
           public: event Handler^ OnHandler;
           public: void __clrcall Runner(bool checkit)
           {
              if(&Objeks::OnHandler != nullptr) 
                OnHandler(checkit);
           }
       };
   }
}
```

I left the default VS 2010 C++/CLI project alone for the most part, I would expect that if your going through the trouble of forward declarations, the using namespace System; would go in the header's also :)

Maybe you did not want to use event?  But it seems to simply the structure.

I added the error check after considering ([Error Compiling C++/CLI Delegate call using Predicate with Array::FindAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649633/error-compiling-c-cli-delegate-call)).