# How do you extern a delegate in .Net C++

Tags: .net, delegates, c++-cli

This is the second question in a series concerning updating the UI from another thread.  I am trying to use a delegate to tell the UI to execute the update function (no data needs to be passed).  I created a delegate in the UI thread and declared it on top of the UI thread:

```
delegate void MyDel();
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
    // .....
    void testFunc()
    {
       this->local_long_textBox->Text = "Test!!!!!!!";
    }
private:
    void startUp()
    {
       MyDel^ DelInst = gcnew MyDel(this,&CotStinger::Form1::testFunc);
```

I would like to pass DelInst to another thread upon creation but when I try to declare MyDel as an extern like this on top of another module:

```
extern delegate MyDel;
```

I get the error:

> Error C2146: syntax error : missing `';'` before identifier `'MyDel'`.

If I try this

```
extern delegate void MyDel();
```

I get the error:

> Error C2144: syntax error : `'void'` should be preceded by `';'`

So how do I get the other class to recognize the delegate type so I can pass the delegate pointer to the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `delegate` keyword is used to define a delegate *type*, not to declare a variable that happens to be some type of delegate. I.e., once the delegate type has been defined, you don't need the `delegate` keyword at any point.

Additionally, global variables of managed types are not allowed in C++/CLI; the usual workaround is to use a logically-static managed class with public static data members that function as globals:

```
delegate void MyDel();
private ref struct Globals abstract sealed
{
    static MyDel^ MyDelInstance;
};

// ...

Globals::MyDelInstance = gcnew MyDel(this, &CotStinger::Form1::testFunc);
```

---

> So how do I get the other class to recognize the delegate type so I can pass the delegate pointer to the constructor?

The same as with any other type -- put it in a header file that both classes can `#include`.

Comment: I copied your code above and got the following message: error C3145: 'myDelInstance' : global or static variable may not have managed type 'CotStinger::MyDel ^'

Comment: The rest of the message is: may not declare a global or static variable, or a member of a native type that refers to objects in the gc heap

Comment: Yes!  So what does the ref struct Globals abstract sealed do?

Comment: @user758362 : If you know C#, it's the exact equivalent of a `static class` in C# except that it has public member accessibility by default rather than private. I.e., it's a managed type with public member accessibility by default that is not allowed to be derived from or instantiated (and so effectively may only have `static` data members and member functions).

Comment: Ok, I included the Form1.h file with the above declarations in my second module and am having difficulty getting that to compile.  What syntax would I use in the second module.  It says it is not found.

Comment: @user758362 : You're saying your Form1.h file contains the definitions of `MyDel` and `Globals`, and some second file is including Form1.h but can't find those type definitions? I don't believe you. ;-]

Comment: I got it.  I needed to separate the delegates into their own .h file.  Including the UI .h file everywhere caused problems.

Comment: @ildjarn why can't I forward declare the delegate just like I can forward declare other managed types? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005892/how-do-i-forward-declare-a-delegate-in-c-cli